# Android Download Manager to Media Store

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager, android-storage

I am downloading files via DownloadManager and can then query the MediaStore and see it is added automatically.

The problem is I don't see how they can be matched. The download id is not the same as the media id and the the download url is not the same the media store url.

How should I match items downloaded from the DownloadManager with the record created in MediaStore?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are different uries for the same file if served by a different provider/authority.

And the id can differ too indeed. If there is an id.

If you select the file by SAF there is again a different uri.

It is unclear to me what you want or need.

If you are looking for a match then compare `.DISPLAY_NAME` and `.RELATIVE_PATH`.

Comment: I need the media id once a file is downloaded via the DownloadManager. I suppose I could use the filename, but that isn't accurate since (I think) files in media store could have the same name.

Comment: Yes. Thats why you should use .RELATIVE_PATH for the folder too. There cannot be files with the same name in a folder.  For what do you need a media id?  You got an id of DownloadManager already so you can determine the download uri.

Comment: `can then query the MediaStore and see it is added automatically.` You can instruct the DownloadManager to update the MediaStore and it will do.

Comment: The user presses download and receives back a download uri once it is complete. I then store that download uri along with my apps internal id for that file. Then the user launches the app again and the MediaStore is queried, now I need to match that MediaStore record with the previously stored item that has the download uri.

Comment: But why?? Why?? You still did not tell why! Why?

Comment: There is other data associated with the file that they are downloading. That data has an internal file id and other useful information for the user to consume the file. So the record in MediaStore needs to be able to get matched with the file data.

Comment: All very vague, sorry. Goid luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I just used the filename, it seems strange that no one has needed to find the record in media store that matches the download that just occurred. I suppose for the vast majority of apps all the data they would need is on the file in the metadata already, so it isn't necessary.

Comment: Normally if you download a file there is no meta data as who would have supplied that?

Comment: In the case of an audio file, for example, the metadata is already in the file. So if you download a song the title, album, artist, is usually accessible from the metadata assuming it was encoded correctly.